# BeatifulSoup4 closes common meta and link tags in the head

Tags: beautifulsoup, meta-tags

```
<head>
<meta name="description" content="Our description">
<meta name="keywords" content="our keywords">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/IN/style.css" type="text/css">
</head
```

Becomes

```
<head>
  <meta name="description" content="Our description">
    <meta name="keywords" content="our keywords">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/IN/style.css" type="text/css">
      </link>
    </meta>
  </meta>
</head>
```

Multiplied by all the tags in the head it starts to get ridiculous. Making the tags self-closing prevents the behavior, but to the extent the behavior is common (this very site, arstechnica, theverge) I think there should be a workaround to disable the behavior. Is there?